# What does green vertical line mean to the left of style in inspect element?

Tags: html, css, inspect-element

I am trying to add a hovering effect to my button and no matter what I do it does not work... I have checked all inherited elements and see none that may conflict with my new hover declaration.

[image]

Can someone please take a look at the picture and tell me what that green line to the left of my hover declaration means?

Comment: i am using firefox because I think it has more options for inspect element than chrome. my hover declaration is also entirely crossed out and i am not sure why, all other conflicting elements i have crossed out.

Comment: If it is related to programming, consider adding the code. If it is with general doubt, it is off topic

Comment: @sagarV what do you mean by that? This relates to programming as you can see clearly it has code

Comment: @sky, that is not code. It is screenshot of properties of an element shown by browser. Both are different

Answer (score -1):

It appears that this line indicates a style targeting a hover state.

Answer (score -1):

It looks you have inline css which is overriding the styles added through class.
For your case to override the inline css you may try using `!important` like below:

```
.nav5link.nodoNavLink:hover{
  background-color: white !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey Raju, thanks! problem with this is then it overrides the original style CSS... so on that first element, it says color xxx andbackground xxx, but if i add important, than THAT element ID normal coloring is no longer working!!